# Why (and how) do foods stick to a pan?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

We all (sooner or later) have noticed that foods relatively high in protein (especially those low in fat) are very prone to sticking to a pan, or in general to any non-specially-coated metal surface. For example really lean white fish, which is almost all protein, is one of those devils which will always want to stick. Likewise, egg whites can stick. To some extent, almost any food that doesn't have a generous amount of easy-rendering fat seems to stick, but higher protein is more sticky.

To counteract this tendency, one learns to compensate by putting some kind of fat (usually oil or butter) into the pan in advance of the food. Most people seem to get the best result by preheating the dry pan some, then adding the oil, letting it get up to temperature, then adding the food.

I was just trying to ask myself what would be a simple and general sketch of what is going on on the surface of a pan when sticking takes place, and in particular:

1) what features of a material (density, chemical composition, elasticity, specific heat,etc.)

2) and of the state of the surface (temperature, roughness, etc.)

have a dominant role in the physics of such a system.

3) Which phenomena (lubrication, intermolecular forces, order-disorder phase-transitions, etc.) are more likely to be responsible for what we experience in our every-day life.

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: yeah.. but I'll answer it anyway..

Comment: also, this has some info in the first paragraph: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/how-do-i-prevent-food-from-sticking-to-a-standard-non-coated-pan

Comment: Independently of the validity of this observation and the physical/chemical mechanisms that are responsible for it, I think the proper experimental procedure to work with the effect to produce deliciously fried food items is being taught in culinary schools around the world. The "sticking" actually happens to be a useful and necessary property, because it transfers more heat to the surface of the food where the Maillard reaction can then do its magic to create flavors that are otherwise lost in the non-stick cooking process.

Comment: Surely fat acts like an oil when heated, making the food(s) it came from less likely to stick. A lack of it would cause friction in the pan and there for an increased chance produce would stick and burn; Protein is pretty sticky as it is so without a fair amount of fat/ oil present it has a high chance of fixing itself to the frying pan.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @JohnRennie I do not agree, take for example lubrication, the tendency for protein-rich foods to stick more easily, etc. I am asking what is the physical counterpart of the bond-dominated explanation that chemist would give.

Comment: This question is for the most part better suited for the Chemistry or Cooking sister sites. There's a tiny bit of physics behind foods sticking to your pans, but the primary reason is chemistry. (The physics side: A pan has little pores that open when the pan heats. The part of the pan underneath the meat contracts on adding the meat. Those pores close and bite down on the meat.) That said, a little stickiness is not bad. I just made a fantastic steak au poivre tonight. The sauce is part of the dish, and the sauce wouldn't come out if there weren't little sticky bits of meat left on the pan.