# Why does bread sticks on a hot pan?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, home-experiment

What causes a slice of bread when placed on a non stick (hot) pan without much oil/butter to stick to it.
And why does it not in presence of butter or oil ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be better suited to the [Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) which deals with cooking at all levels.

Comment: It seems like it's a question for physical-chemistry, which is technically a tag under physics. I could see there being a feynman-like explanation for it (but it would be very chemistry-ish)

Comment: See related question [Why (and how) do foods stick to a pan?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154006) which was not closed, but has no answer. Chemistry SE might be a better site to ask, since the explanation is likely to involve chemical reactions rather than physical chemistry.